# Countdown seconds, update database and loop the Countdown

Tags: javascript, timer, countdown

i'm trying to do a small countdown script only in seconds that update my database when it reaches 0 and start the countdown process again.

Example:

**HTML**

```
<p>Updating your profile in <span class="countdown"></span> seconds.</p>
```

I need the profile to be updated every 780 seconds, once the countdown reaches 0 it makes a ajax call to update the profile and resets the countdown to repete all over again.

Also i've tryed some countdown scripts but the user can change the script in browser, is there any possibility to protect the website from users changing the code?

Thanks

Comment: You can minify and uglify your js making it difficult to read and understand, but since it is running on the client there is no sure-fire way to prevent the user from changing the code.

Comment: is there any way to do this server side?

Comment: Not really because you have no way of knowing if the user is still on your page once it is served (if you're using PHP at least). What's the purpose of this? Security?

Comment: Im making a website for a friend of mine that streams, and he wants to give hes viewers points every lets say 780seconds (10 minutes) so they can spend them to earn giveaways... so i need the script to start a countdown on pageload and repete every 780 seconds and update the database..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Im making a website for a friend of mine that streams, and he wants to
>   give hes viewers points every lets say 780seconds (10 minutes) so they
>   can spend them to earn giveaways... so i need the script to start a
>   countdown on pageload and repete every 780 seconds and update the
>   database..

This is more a security question it seems to me. You're wondering how you can securely track timed events on the client.

You confront some problems: anyone who knows how can change the code to make the AJAX call more often (thereby giving them more points) so client side isn't feasible, but neither can you can track user interaction with your page through server side code alone.

So I think what you want is a combination of both. You want periodic ajax calls on the client side, but you want to verify the timing based on some code the server side - you probably want to send AJAX calls, but verify the timing and the user identity by checking a session or cookie id.

Comment: I just dont want the user to edit the seconds of the script, becouse they cant realy update anything directly, becouse the update page only accepts ajax requests.. so i just need to make sure the end user cant edit the 780 seconds to lets say 10 seconds..

Comment: That's my point- you can't. But what you can do is keep track of the user and the time on the server side so that when the AJAX call comes in, you can say "this call happened too soon, disregard it and don't credit any points".

Answer (score 0):

When doing the database update add a timestamp to it then when you do any other calls check against the timestamp to see if 780 seconds has passed.

if time is more than 780 then do that db update if not, dont do anything.

Comment: ohh, thats actualy a good idea, im using laravel, so there is allways a timsestamp available. thanks, however i suck at javascript, cant figure out how to do the script :p